# Android Activity not automatically in manifest?

Tags: java, android

I thought Android Studio automatically adds a new Activity in AndroidManifest.XML for you if you created a new Activity file. Do we actually have to add it manually?

Comment: Normally it should if it is not working in your part file a bug report and add the steps in which how you reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall it ever automatically adding new Activities outside of the initial setup wizard.

But yes, if it does not automatically add it, then you'll have to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add it manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you add Activity by this step showing in following image, it will automatically add it to manifest and also create a layout xml file for your activity.

[image]
 Otherwise you have to add it manually. Hope this help you understand.

Comment: Even though we add like this, The Manifest doesn't get updated automatically. This is happening in the Android Studio Chipmuk patch 1 update